# how to call stored procedure that return values from multible tables using entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

iam new to Entity framework
i have learned about using SP and how to map (insert \ delete \ update) 
in every table
and how to import function to call SP that returns values from one table

my question is hot can i to call SP that returns multiple columns from multiple tables

in LINQ to SQL generating class that represents all columns that returned by SP
how can i use Entity Framework in this case

thanks in advance Every Body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EF v4 and VS 2010, you can create ComplexType containing all necessary columns while creating FunctionImport returning a collection of these ComplexTypes.
If you are using EF v1 and VS 2008, the process is more complex. 
You will have to create an entity in SSDL, CSDL and MSL manually and then map FunctionImport to return a collection of these entities.

Comment: Thanks Devart for advice
and you are right i tried with vs 2010 and it easier than vs 2008
and EF1 
thanks again for advice